# my build is working on VS code but not on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-code, wonderpush

When I launched my app on iOS on vs code, the build is successfull but the app crashed when you change the screen.

When I open my Xcode the build failed directly with an error

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Klaaap-feojqlwiozdtgsczazhciamgtbgk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
1 error generated.
```

This is my `Podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '14.2'

target 'Klaaap' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])





  pod 'RNSoundLevel', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound-level'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  target 'KlaaapTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'Klaaap-tvOS' do
  # Pods for Klaaap-tvOS

  target 'Klaaap-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension' do
  platform :ios, '10.0'

  # Pods for WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension
  pod 'WonderPushExtension', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Also my Xcode:

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, says you are trying to tell your cocoapods to use a target named `WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension` and it doesn't exist in your project. Check the names of your targets

Comment: yes but do you know if this error can be the problem for my build ?

Comment: yes, cocoapods can't run because you've given it invalid instructions. If cocoapods can't download your dependencies, then your project won't build. Even if this wasn't the problem, if one of your core critical tools is reporting an error, you need to fix it or it will break something

Comment: yes for sure, i just don't find where i have to change it because in Xcode the WonderPushNotification is there :(

Comment: nobody else can help unless you show us. Upload a screenshot of your targets in xcode and copy your podfile here

Comment: Thanks Simon, i just update my post

Comment: Everything red in that screenshot is missing from your project.

Comment: that screenshot is not of your targets, thats of your code. On the left hand side, where all the folders / source code is, click on the project name "Klaaap" with the blue xcode icon next to it. Then the middle view should update to have tabs for "General", "Signing & Capabilities" etc. Along the left hand side should be "PROJECT" and "TARGETS". Screenshot this section to show us the list of targets

Comment: thanks Simon just Update

Comment: Yes, so back to the error message you got. "Can't find target `WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension`". You have told cocoapods to add something to a target named `WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension`, your screenshot shows no such target. If you are following a tutorial or using some example project, you have missed some steps somewhere, or copied something you should not have

Comment: So now i have an other error !] The `Klaaap [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Klaaap/Pods-Klaaap.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: I copied the first line into google and the first result, is your issue with screenshots on how to fix it: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5981

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that, you have asked cocoapods to do something to a Target called "WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension", but one doesn't exist. From your edits and screenshots above, you never created one.

Out of interest I googled what `WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension` was, and it brought me to the WonderPush iOS documentation. From the looks of it you are trying to incorporate this third party service into your app, but have not followed the second half of their documentation, showing how to create the Target and add the service extension.

You need to go back and start again, making sure to follow all of the steps in the below link.

Link to React-Native tutorial:
https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/mobile-push-notifications-react-native